# multiple lstlisting for commands and outputs

Tags: listings

I wanted to have some commands and outputs in my document. Is it possible to have two seperate `lstlisting`s?

The command would be:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=cl, caption = Command Caption, label=imstat_flat]
  ccdred> imstat sp0014.fits,sp0015.fits,sp0016.fits,sp0017.fits,flat.fits
\end{lstlisting}
```

And the output would be:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=cl, caption = Output Caption, label=imstat_flat_output]
        IMAGE           NPIX      MEAN      STDDEV    MIN       MAX
        sp0014.fits     41984     7699.     1134.     2881.     10193.
        sp0015.fits     41984     7524.     1110.     2895.     9953.
        sp0016.fits     41984     7455.     1100.     2819.     9863.
        sp0017.fits     41984     7417.     1095.     2813.     9800.
          flat.fits     41984     7511.     1107.     2863.     9917.
\end{lstlisting}
```

Next I want to refer to these as such:

```
The output of the Command \ref{imstat_flat} can be seen in Output \ref{imstat_flat_output}.
```

I want the numbering to be different for command and outputs. I wish to have `Command` as a suffix for commands and `Output` as a suffix for outputs.

I there a way to achieve this? Any Idea is welcomed. Such as, is there any other package to be used for outputs?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you.